# conda deactivate hangs, within tmux session

Tags: python, bash, conda, tmux

I've looked through multiple issues with tmux and conda but haven't yet seen this issue of conda deactivate hanging so I will try to explain my issues here in detail:

### Primary issue (seen in other questions):

In tmux sessions past the initial session, python is reset to `/usr/bin/python/` instead of the base conda environment

When running `tmux new` the `which python` in the first session returns:

`/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/python` as expected.

`echo $PATH` in first session:

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/X.X.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/X.X.0/bin
```

If I split this window into another pane or open a new window, `which python` returns:
`/usr/bin/python/` and the PATH variable is rearranged.

`echo $PATH` in subsequent sessions:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/X.X.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/X.X.0/bin
```

Now both of these sessions are sourcing `~/.bash_profile` (I have added an echo command to be sure), and both are login shells (`echo $0` returns -bash).

There is no `~/.profile` file and it doesn't seem like `~/.bashrc` is being sourced at all.

### Potentially related issue when trying to workaround:

`conda deactivate` hangs but then after sending `^C` will show the env deactivated. I'm not entirely sure if that is happening correctly however.

This does not happen if not in a `tmux` session or if I deactivate from the first session within a tmux.

All in all I'm generally confused what the differences are between the sessions and why conda is having a difficult time with environments within some sessions but not all bash sessions. Any troubleshooting steps or advice would be greatly appreciated as I've dealt with this issue for half the year and none of the previous issues have fixed it.

Thank you in advance

Addition: tmux version is `tmux 3.2a` and conda version is `conda 4.7.12`

Comment: Creating a new window or pane creates a new shell spawned by `tmux`, not the current window or pane. There's no virtual environment in it to deactivate in the first place, which is why when you cancel `conda deactivate` it appears to be deactivated. I don't know that `tmux` has anything to do with this.

Comment: The new panes show the prompt with the `(base)` when started. The issue only seems to happen in `tmux` so why do you think it's not a tmux related issue?